# Como adicionar mais dados á uma planilha usando o R?

Tags: r

Estou fazendo um trabalho de bioinformatica utilizando dados de pacientes, cada paciente possui um codigo e esse trabalho foi dividido entre outros colegas também, cada um ficou com uma parte. Pois bem, preciso anexar as partes deles, que também possuem o codigo dos mesmos pacientes antes dos dados, junto á minha parte porem os codigos não seguem uma ordem, então esta tudo misturado, precisaria que por exemplo, o codigo rs39023 da minha planilha recebesse o codigo rs39023 da planilha dos meus colegas,uma espécie de mescla mas sem misturar dados errados. São aproximadamente 1050 linhas(1050 pacientes), o que fica bem dificil fazer no ctrl+c ctrl+v. Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você deve estar procurando por [`left_join`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/two-table.html)

Comment: no entanto, sua pergunta não está muito clara. coloque uma amostrinha desses bancos de dados que você está querendo juntar. Ou, se não puder compartilhá-lo crie um exemplo.

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo de dados que estou utilizando: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9xKCw_RPCnBRGhZWmlHWmlOZGs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: não tenho acesso ao google drive (rede corporativa) você consegue editar a sua pergunta e colocar uma parte dos dados?

Comment: adicionei como foto, não sei se ajuda D: tentei copiar e colar direto, porem ficou totalmente bagunçado

Comment: todos os arquivos possuem esses mesmo formato?

Comment: todos possuem apenas a primeira coluna(SNP) igual, porem não nessa ordem! as outras colunas deveriam ser anexadas no arquivo "principal" só que nos seus devidos codigos SNP. No caso, seria como copiar as 7 colunas do SNP  rs1000000 e colar no arquivo principal na linha onde esta o SNP rs1000000 também, não sei se consegui ser claro D:

Comment: Leia esta resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124326/6036 eu acho que é exatamente o que você precisa.

Comment: Acho que era isso mesmo! Vou quebrar um pouco a cabeça agora para tentar usar! Muito obrigado!