# Como combinar dois dataframes na ordem correta utilizando R

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv('train.csv')  
train1 <- train[train$variavel3 == 1]  
train2 <- train[train$variavel3 == 0]  
fit1 <- rpart(variavel1~variavel2)  
fit2 <- rpart(variavel1~variavel2)  
dftest <- read.csv('test.csv')  
dftest1 <- test[test$variavel3 == 1]  
dftest2 <- test[test$variavel3 == 0]  
prediction1 <- predict(fit1, dftest1)  
prediction2 <- predict(fit2, dftest2)
```

dataframe1-------------dataframe2
x1---x2-----------------x1------x2
1----0-------------------2-------0
3----0-------------------4-------1
6----1-------------------5-------1

Eu quero juntar os dataframes de forma que x1 fique na ordem correta

Comment: Ola Pedro, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Poderia editar a sua pergunta e especificar o que você quer dizer por "juntar"? Seria apenas criar um dataframe com os dados de `prediction1` seguidos dos dados de `prediction2`?

Comment: Nao seria so juntar, como por exemplo usar o rbind, pois tem que ficar na ordem de uma variavel. acabei de descobrir a funçao **merge**. Vou testa-la agora

Comment: A ideia do **merge** foi boa mas nao deu certo, esta dizendo "no data available in table"

Comment: Talvez vc esteja procurando isso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124319/6036

Comment: Dei uma melhorada na pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Consegui a resposta.
Juntei os dois data frames com um rbind()
e depois utilizei um arrange() para ordenar da forma que queria.
Muito obrigado pela ajuda de todos