# Existem alguma função em R similar ao PROCV do excel?

Tags: r, data.frame

No meu caso tenho dois data.frames:

```
> head(Trecho)
         Xt       Yt Zt
1 -75.56468 1.642710  0
2 -74.56469 1.639634  0
3 -73.56469 1.636557  0
4 -72.56470 1.633480  0
5 -71.56470 1.630403  0
6 -70.56471 1.627326  0

    > head(TrechoSim)
        Xs        Ys Zs
1 -71.7856 -0.509196  0
2 -71.7856 -0.509196  0
3 -71.7856 -0.509196  0
4 -71.7856 -0.509196  0
5 -71.7856 -0.509196  0
6 -71.7856 -0.509196  0
```

O data frame `Trecho` tem aproximadamente 5 mil linhas e o `TrechoSim` tem  20 mil linhas. Semelhante ao `PROCV` do Excel, preciso buscar o valor mais próximo onde Xt = Xs (no excel uso o VERDADEIRO, e retorna o primeiro valor mais próximo de Xt). Não existe uma tolerância para essa proximidade. Preciso de todos os valores do data frame `Trecho` com seu respectivo valor mais próximo de `TrechoSim`.
Tentei `difference_inner_join` mas ele retorna valores `NA` em algumas linhas.

Grata,

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/124326/6036

Comment: @DanielFalbel essa solução é para valores buscados IDÊNTICOS. No meu caso é um valor similar, pois nenhum será idêntico, ou caso ocorra serão poucos.

Comment: desculpe, li rapido! Talvez vc esteja atrás disso: https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin

Comment: @DanielFalbel já testei esse. Ele pede uma distância. E a minha distância varia. Temp <- difference_left_join(Trecho, TrechoSim, by = c(Xt="Xs") , max_dist = .1 ). E alguns valores retornam NA.

Comment: Como fica a questão de múltiplas correspondências para o objetivo do problema? P.e., nos dados de exemplo, o valor 5 da base `Trecho` poderia ser mapeada para qualquer um dos seis valores iniciais de `TrechoSim`. É aceitável que duas entradas de `Trecho` sejam associadas à mesma entrada de `TrechoSim`?

Comment: @EriksonK. desconsidere esses valores iniciais, pois como é uma coleta de dados de um carro simulado, nesse momento ele está parado. Eu fiz no Excel e funcionou com o PROCV.

Comment: Acho que a solucao mais simples vai ser usando a library [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin). Voce pode atualizar a pergunta incluindo o codigo que voce usou com `difference_inner_join`? Tambem seria uma boa atualizar o titulo da pergunta para deixar claro que vc quer usar fuzzy match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu não tenho os conjuntos de dados originais ou o Excel instalado para testar a função `PROCV`, mas creio que o código abaixo resolveu o problema.

A função `procura` calcular a diferença, em valor absoluto, entre um número e um vetor e encontra qual posição do vetor é mais próxima deste número.

O código não está otimizado, mas imagino que deva rodar razoavelmente rápido em computadores atuais. Testei o mesmo código aumentando os tamanhos amostrais dos dados simulados para 5000 e 20000 e meu código levou menos de 2 segundos para fazer todas as comparações.

```
Trecho    <- data.frame(Xt=rnorm(5),  Yt=rnorm(5),  Zt=0)
TrechoSim <- data.frame(Xs=rnorm(20), Ys=rnorm(20), Zt=0)

procura <- function(x, y){
  return(which.min(abs(x-y)))
}

index <- 0

for (j in 1:length(Trecho$Xt)){
  index[j] <- procura(Trecho$Xt[j], TrechoSim$Xs)
}

Trecho
TrechoSim[index, ]
```

Comment: Marcus Nunes tem como inserir as colunas do `TrechoSim[index,]` às suas respectivas linhas do `Trecho`? Criando um data frame `Xt Yt Zt Xs Ys Zs`

Comment: Tente `cbind(Trecho, TrechoSim[index, ])`.

Comment: Fiz assim e deu certo `Temp <- {cbind(Trecho, data.frame(TrechoSim[index, ], 
        row.names = seq_along(Trecho$Xt)), deparse.level = 0)}`