# Inserir valor de vetor de um data.frame em outro data.frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Eu tenho dois data frames. O primeiro dele possui 2185 observações e o segundo tem apenas 9.

O primeiro data frame, cujo nome de é `dados`, contém as seguintes variáveis: `local`, `parc`, `arv`, `DAP`, `Ht`, `Hf`, `epiteto` e `genero`.

O segundo, com nome de `coordg` contém `parcela`, `longitude`, `latitude` e `Eg`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de inserir os valores da variavel ambiental `Eg` do data frame `coordg` no data frame `dados`, repetindo o valor de `Eg` para cada `arv`, de acordo com o nome das `parc` em comum entre os data frames, conforme abaixo:

```
   Local    parc   arv  DAP     Ht    Hf   copa      genero       epiteto      Eg
  varzea    MZVT2   1   11.777  14.1  13.5  0.6      Euterpe       oleracea    0.016
  varzea    MZVT2   2   13.782  17.4  14.0  3.4      Euterpe       oleracea    0.016
  varzea    MZVT2   3    9.326  11.1   4.0  7.1      Euterpe       oleracea    0.016
  varzea    MZVT2   4   25.305  20.8  12.0  8.8   Calycophyllum  spruceanum    0.016
  varzea    MZVT2   5   10.345  11.2   4.0  7.2   Indeterminada Indeterminada  0.016
```

Comment: Você precisa de um `left_join`, veja as respostas dessa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124319/procurar-valores-em-um-data-frame-e-adicionar-em-outro-r/124326#124326

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro sugiro transformar o nome da coluna parcela em parc, para ficar igual nos dois dataframes:

```
names(coordg)[1] <- "parc"
```

A função `merge` pode lhe ajudar. O código ficaria assim:

```
dados2 <- merge(dados, coordg[ ,c("parc","Eg")], by="parc")
```

Lembrando que o `dados 2` será no novo dataframe com todas as colunas do `dados` mais a `Eg` de cada `parc`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar a função `subset`para verificar qual valor da variavel `parc` você precisa utilizar:

```
subset(coordg, parcela %in% dados$parc)
```

isso retornará o valor necessário do campo `parcela` do dataframe `coordg`

Assim, você só precisará adicionar uma nova coluna no dataframe e preenche-la com este valor:

```
dados$eg <- subset(coordg, parcela %in% dados$parc)[4]
```

Ou ainda

```
dados$eg <- subset(coordg, parcela %in% dados$parc)["Eg"]
```

Sendo que o número 4 refere-se ao número da coluna em que se encontram os valores de `eg` no dataframe `coordg`.

Isso só irá funcionar quando o dataframe `dados` tiver *apenas* o mesmo valor para `parc` em todas as linhas. Caso tenha valores diferentes, será necessário modificar (acho que um `for`já poderia resolver caso fosse necessário). Se for este caso, por favor, comente que procurarei ver como resolver.

Comment: Vou verificar. Mas ja agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Quando rodei para adicionar a nova coluna no dataframe,apareceu um erro na substituição, informando que Eg é constituído por 9 linhas e os dados por 2538, assim não podendo realizar a operação:                                                                        
   Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Eg", value = list(Eg=c(0.0167105529787358, : replacement has 9 rows, data has 2538