# Unir data frames

Tags: r

Tenho dois data frame (ver abaixo) com informações de consumo e ganho de animais. O consumo foi coletado a cada dia e o ganho em intervalos maiores. Quero juntar um ao lado do outro, tendo uma coluna de Animal, Dia, Consumo e Ganho. Nesse caso, no ganho, onde não tem informação, manter como NA.
Como posso fazer isso?

```css
DfConsumo
Animal Dia Consumo
5 2 1959.44
5 4 2015.125
5 5 2062.513
5 6 2102.862
5 7 2157.486
5 8 2213.519
5 9 2279.803
5 10 2317.222
5 11 2428.641
6 3 2000
6 4 2041.661
6 5 2049.473
6 6 2111.409
6 7 2149.92
6 8 2153.251
6 9 2207.271
6 10 2246.633
6 11 2297.115

DfGanho
Animal Dia Ganho
5 2 0.95
5 9 0.95
6 3 0.95
6 9 0.96
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Procurar valores em um data.frame e adicionar em outro (R)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124319/procurar-valores-em-um-data-frame-e-adicionar-em-outro-r)

Answer (score 6):

A função `merge` com a opção `all = T` resolve o seu problema. Veja código abaixo:

```
DfConsumo <- data.frame(
  Animal = c(rep(5,9), rep(6,9)),
  Dia = c(2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11),
  Consumo = c(1959.44,2015.125,2062.513,2102.862,2157.486,2213.519,2279.803,2317.222,2428.641,
          2000,2041.661,2049.473,2111.409,2149.92,2153.251,2207.271,2246.633,2297.115)
)
DfGanho = data.frame(Animal = c(5,5,6,6), Dia = c(2,9,3,9), Ganho = c(.95,.95,.95,.96))

Df <- merge(DfConsumo, DfGanho, all = T)
```