# Criar uma coluna indexada a outra no R

Tags: r

Boa tarde !

Sou novo no R e tenho uma base de dados onde preciso incluir uma coluna, entretanto os valores desta coluna precisam estar atrelados aos valores de outra coluna.

No caso, tenho a coluna `ano` (2006:2016) e preciso criar a coluna `PIB` (com valores específicos para cada ano).

Os anos não seguem a sequencia, alguns pulam.

Estou usando `dCoopCred$ano` e `dCoopCred$PIB`.

Exemplo:

```
ano     PIB
2006    4,0
2007    6,1
2008    5,1
2009    -0,1
2010    7,5
2011    4,0
2012    1,9
2013    3,0
2014    0,5
2015    -3,8
2016    -3,6
```

Entretanto, são 10mil linhas, os anos não seguem uma sequência.

Desculpem qualquer coisa, é minha primeira postagem aqui.

Grato desde já.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow Português! Sua pergunta não está muito clara. Você quer que os anos estejam em ordem? Se sim: `sort(dCoopCred$ano)`. Se não, dê uma olhada em como fazer uma pergunta [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/825/80049).

Comment: Não compreendo, a coluna `PIB` não é a coluna da direita?

Comment: Olá, obrigado !

A coluna da direita é o PIB. a coluna ano apresenta valor de 2006 a 2016, mas são 10mil linhas, logo, não seguem uma sequencia.

Na linha de cada ano, quero adicionar seu respectivo valor do PIB.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Procurar valores em um data.frame e adicionar em outro (R)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124319/procurar-valores-em-um-data-frame-e-adicionar-em-outro-r)

Comment: @RicardoTheodoro marquei como duplicada, pq acho que o que você precisa é um `left_join`.

Comment: @DanielFalbel olá! no caso, não sei como fazer para pegar os valores do ano e relaciona-los com o valor do PIB. 

No exemplo que você deu, ele pegou duas colunas com os mesmos valores, no meu caso são diferentes.

Eu teria que atribuir o valor do PIB ao ano, por exemplo: se o ano for 2006, o valor do PIB será 4, se o valor do ano for 2012, o valor do PIB será 1,9.

Comment: @RicardoTheodoro O left join funciona assim: você possui duas tabelas que possuem uma chave em comum (no seu caso, o ano) e você quer trazer as colunas de uma tabela para a outra assegurando que as chaves batem. Não é isso que você precisa?

Comment: @DanielFalbel olá, era isso mesmo ! desculpa, não soube como aplicar o exemplo para o meu caso.
acabei fazendo através de um for().

`dCoopCred$PIB <- c(0)
for(i in row(dCoopCred)){
  if(dCoopCred$ano[i]==2006){
    dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(4)  
  }dCoopCred$PIB <- c(0)
for(i in row(dCoopCred)){
  if(dCoopCred$ano[i]==2006){
    dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(4)  
  }else if (dCoopCred$ano[i]==2007){
    dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(6.1)
  }....`

Mas muito obrigado !

Comment: @RicardoTheodoro quando tiver um tempo escrevo um exemplo aqui. Abraços,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi através de um for:

```
dCoopCred$PIB <- c(0) for(i in row(dCoopCred)){  
if(dCoopCred$ano[i]==2006){dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(4)     
} else if (dCoopCred$ano[i]==2007){dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(6.1)   
 }else if (dCoopCred$ano[i]==2008){dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(5.1)   
}else if (dCoopCred$ano[i]==2009){dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(-0.1)   
}else if (dCoopCred$ano[i]==2010){dCoopCred$PIB[i] <- c(7.5) 
}....
}}
```