# Filtrar data frame de acordo com índices (linhas) armazenadas num vetor

Tags: r, dataframe

Olá, 
tenho um data frame onde armazeno informações sobre pontos turísticos.
Exemplo na imagem:[image: Dados do meu data frame]

e tenho vetor como esse:
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thj7U.png)  1  3  4 11 12 13 14 16 29 30 41  6  7  8  9 10  5 15 17 27

esse vetor no caso é um vetor dinâmico;

O que estou tentando fazer é gerar um novo data.frame com as linhas correspondentes aos números do meu vetor.

Em suma, seria filtrar o meu data.frame principal de acordo com o vetor que tenho com as linhas q estarao no data.frame filtrado.

o quis dizer seria: exemplo: se meu vetor for [2 4 6] meu segundo data;frame sera formado pelas linhas 2 4 e 6 do data.frame principal (o do print)

Alguma dica? desde já agradeço;

Comment: Não estou entendendo bem. Você quer filtrar um `data.frame` baseado em valores de outro `data.frame`, é isso?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Procurar valores em um data.frame e adicionar em outro (R)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124319/procurar-valores-em-um-data-frame-e-adicionar-em-outro-r)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se entendi bem, você quer selecionar as linhas do data frame com as informações sobre os pontos turísticos a partir do vetor dinâmico, correto?

Seja então `df` seu data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(X = rnorm(100), Y = sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = T))
```

O seu vetor dinâmico:

```
linhas <- sample(1:100, 15)
```

Para selecionar somente as linhas, você pode fazer:

```
df[linhas, ]
```

Comment: o quis dizer seria: exemplo: se meu vetor for [2 4 6] meu segundo data;frame sera formado pelas linhas 2 4 e 6 do data.frame principal (o do print)

Comment: então o código que coloquei como resposta faz o que você quer

Answer (score 2):

Expandindo a resposta dada pelo @RafaelCunha. Se no case você quer filtrar um `data.frame` baseado em outro `data.frame`, você pode fazer do seguinte jeito.

```
set.seed(1)
d1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 20, T), col2 = runif(20), stringsAsFactors = F)
d2 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(LETTERS, 20, T), col3 = sample(c(1:10), 20, T), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

### Solução base

Filtre `d1` baseado no vetor resultante do seu filtro em `d2`:

```
# base
res_base <- d1[d1$col1 %in% unique(d2[d2$col3 < 5, "col1"]), ]
```

### Solução base com junção (merge)

Se a sua base de dados for grande, talvez seja melhor usar `merge` para filtrar `d1` usando do conceito de inner joins (i.e. cada linha em `d1` e `d2` precisam ter em comum valores dado atraves de uma chave (key)):

```
res_base_m  <- merge(d1, d2[d2$col3 < 5, ][1], by = "col1")
```

### Outras soluções

#### dplyr

`dplyr` é um pacote para manipulação de dados que obedece ao padrão de sintaxe do `tidyverse`. O primeiro jeito é simplesmente filtrando os valores achados em `d2` e filtrando-os em `d1` através do verbo `filter`. `dplyr` é bastante intuitivo nesse aspecto. Também podemos usar `inner_join` do mesmo pacote e é bastante recomendado se você está fazendo isso com uma grande base de dados.

```
# carregue pacote
library(dplyr)
res_dplyr <- filter(d1, col1 %in% pull(filter(d2, col3 < 5), col1))

res_dplyr_m <- inner_join(d1, select(filter(d2, col3 < 5), col1), by = "col1")
```

#### data.table

O pacote `data.table` é conhecido pela sua sintaxe sucinta e pela eficiência na computação. É bastante rápido e obedece a sintaxe `DT[i, j, by]`, onde `i` são linhas, `j` colunas e `by` é agrupamento. No primeiro exemplo, filtramos `d2` pelos valores desejados em `col3` e depois usamos o vetor resultante `col1` de `d2` para filtrar no `i` de `d1`. O segundo exemplo é junção realizada por `data.table`: `X[Y, on = _key_, nomatch = 0L]`.

```
# carregue o pacote
library(data.table)
setDT(d1)
setDT(d2)

res_dt <- d1[col1 %in% d2[col3 < 5, col1], ]

res_dt_m <- d1[d2[col3 < 5, .(col1)], on = "col1", nomatch = 0L]
```

Comment: o quis dizer seria: exemplo: se meu vetor for [2 4 6] meu segundo data;frame sera formado pelas linhas 2 4 e 6 do data.frame principal (o do print)